# How to insert <em> tag when exceeding 140 limit i.e. going negative?

Tags: jquery, html, css

is it possible to somehow put  on the chars that are typed in when the user has exceeded the 140 characters limit, and is now in -1 negative etc. Like, modify the background of the text to be red.

```
$(".comment-box").keydown(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var text_max = 140;
    var length_reached = $(this).val().length;
    var remaining = text_max - length_reached;

    $(parent).find('.counter').html(remaining);

    if (remaining < 5 || remaining >= text_max) $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", true);
    else $(parent).find(".btn").prop("disabled", false);
 });
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/56/

**EDIT: are wrap or wrapInner good to use, I am using keyup event which might be a problem, as it adds too many em tags, is there a good solution to get each char after 140 limit and wrap append each inside one single  ?**

Here's a screenshot from Twitter, I want to highlight text like that:

[image]

Comment: You don't need em. Look into font-style

Comment: The real question is: how do you style only *some* text in a `textarea`.

Comment: @lbstr         That's exactly the issue here, I want to add a background to each char that is added, when the counter reports - negative.

Comment: @Dave           I know about that, but how should I make this in jQuery, so that after the zero 0 for every negative keep one background, it will look as when you select a text.

Comment: A standard textarea doesn't let you style only part of the text. You could turn the background of the _whole_ textarea red easily enough. http://jsfiddle.net/3sCfG/59/

Comment: @nnnnnn         Yeah, the whole background is very easy, but I do not want that, do you know how to do it specifically, is it possible to add <em></em> ....

Comment: I refer you back to my first sentence: "A standard textarea doesn't let you style only part of the text."

Comment: @nnnnnn         Twitter does this!

Comment: twitter use div instead of textarea

Comment: @AbrahamUribe       So they mask a textarea with a DIV, how? Can anyone point me to a tutorial or a quick jsfiddle, really need to learn masking of UI, thanks a lot :)

Comment: <div contenteditable="true"></div>

Comment: @AbrahamUribe        This will never work in IE7, IE8 & IE9! It's HTML5 attribute. Can anyone, if possible show me how to solve this with CSS, as that makes it possible to mask things. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: _"This will never work in IE7, IE8 & IE9! It's HTML5 attribute."_ - I think you'll find that `contenteditable` worked at least as far back as IE **5.5**.

Comment: right: http://caniuse.com/contenteditable

Comment: @nnnnnn         If IE5.5 has supported this attribute, I'll use it, because it will work in all current IEs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't style only some parts of a `textarea`, but you can do that with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable). What you should do is create a standard div (style it as a textarea) and make that contenteditable. Then put an onkey event in the div and check if the length is higher than 140. If it is get text, slice it, and apply an html to the excess.

Note that you want to get text content with `element.textContent` and write the html to `element.innerHTML`.

Another thing you should do is handle paste events because by default the browsers copy the html, so they will mess your contenteditable.

EDIT:
If you have to use it in a form you need a `textarea` or an `input hidden` where to store the div content and send in the request.

To do that you can do something like this in jquery:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    var input = $('#inputdiv').text();
    if(input.length <= 140) {
        $('#formtextarea').val(input);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Or you could do that with ajax.

```
function sendStuff() {
    $.post("test.php", { message: $('#inputdiv').text()})
    .done(function(data) {
         // do something here
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, this helped a lot, I will work on this, right now! Thanks a lot, btw, will this have support under IE9, Android, iPhone, iPad and so on? Thanks!

Comment: `contenteditable` has worked in IE since version **5.5**. As for other browsers: http://caniuse.com/contenteditable (Of course, mobile users often use browsers not on your list.)

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot! I am happy! Thanks a lot, I think I can solve this now, but before I mark answer and close this thread, I need to test! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @N1xx1, I found this two lines after the div, <textarea name="status" class="tweet-box-shadow" id="tweet-box-reply-to-334934164774191107"></textarea>, is that content in the div passed to this hidden textarea and then submitted?

Comment: Uhm yes. You would need something like that to pass that in the form. You have to dynamically edit that at computation or at submit since contenteditables aren't form elements.

Comment: @N1xx1, I'll use the div's keyup, to add the same value live to the textarea, except when it exceeds the limit, while the user sees the chars added after zero i.e. in negative count as well, while behind the scene, the value adding to the hidden textarea has stopped at zero.

Comment: This is not needed, you have to keep a verification serverside anyway.

Comment: @N1xx1           Why isn't it needed, I'll need to add the same content to the <textarea> and once submitted, the PHP will handle the rest in the background, will use Ajax.

Comment: If he's using jQuery you should be suggesting the `.text()` method and `.html()` method to get/set the content instead of `innerHTML` and and `textContent`.

Comment: @N1xx1           Do you think wrap or wrapInner are good to use, I am using keyup which might be a problem, as it adds too many em tags, is there a good solution to get each char after 140 limit and wrap append each inside one single <em></em> ?