# How can I make a textarea with character limit highlighting like Twitter?

Tags: javascript, twitter, textarea

Twitter's submit tweet textbox highlights the characters that are over the character limit:

[image]

As you can see, the characters that overrun the character limit are highlighted in red. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Can you show your HTML and what you've tried?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#post-infinity").keyup(function() {

    var maxLength = 200;
    var length = $(this).val().length;

    $("#message-count").text(maxLength - length);

    if (length > maxLength) {

      $("#message-count").css({
        "color": "#ccc"
      });

      $("#button-send").attr({
        "disabled": "disabled"
      });

    } else {

      $("#message-count").css({
        "color": "#6B6B6B"
      });

      $("#button-send").removeAttr("disabled");

    }

  });

});

So red highlight ? I do not know how.

Comment: How can we get in the red?

Comment: No, please show the code in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find the necessary solution and required code here:

[How to insert <em> tag when exceeding 140 limit i.e. going negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950016/how-to-insert-em-tag-when-exceeding-140-limit-i-e-going-negative)

...and here:

[REGEX - Highlight part over 19 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314126/regex-highlight-part-over-19-chars)

Your question appears to be duplicitous.

Note: I didn't have the option to post the above links as a comment (i.e. privilege contingent on reputation).

Here's the code as per Simon Kuang's recommendation (see comments):

## HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Your text here</h3>
   <div contenteditable="true" id="myDiv">edit me
  </div>
  <p>
    <h3>Stuff over 19 characters</h3>
  <div id="extra">
  </div>
  <p>
    <h3>Sample output</h3>
    <div id="sample">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS:

```
.highlight {
 color:red;
}
```

## JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDiv').keyup(function() {
    var content = $('#myDiv').html();
    var extra = content.match(/.{19}(.*)/)[1];

    $('#extra').html(extra);

    var newContent = content.replace(extra, "<span class='highlight'>" + extra + "</span>");
    $('#sample').html(newContent);
  });
});
```

Comment: You'll want to reproduce that material in your answer.

Comment: So, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950016/how-to-insert-em-tag-when-exceeding-140-limit-i-e-going-negative

Comment: Don't forget to place your JavaScript code within the necessary script tags: `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @Popnoodles - Effectively, yes though it's noteworthy to mention that the code is derived from the second link and that the CSS has been nominally adapted.

Comment: I made an example with the code from this answer: https://codepen.io/felipealbuquerq/pen/QWBOYGM

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example, show alert when the  limit is reached  and thereafter highlight all the characters entered.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#text_text');
  var warning = $('#warning');
  var char_limit = 30;
  input.on('keyup', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val.length > parseInt(char_limit)) {
      alert("limit reached");
      warning.html('hello').css('display', 'block');
      l = val.length
      var input = document.getElementById("text_text");
      input.setSelectionRange(char_limit, l);
      input.focus();
    } else {
      warning.css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#warning {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_box">
  <textarea name="msg" cols="50" rows="5" id="text_text"></textarea>

  <div id="warning"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pattern)

html

```
<data></data><br />
<textarea maxlength="20" placeholder="20 character limit"></textarea>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("keyup", "textarea", function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).val().length >= 20) {
            $("data").text($(e.target).attr("placeholder"))
            .fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(9000);
        };
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/8RScd/