# How to save the cursor position in a Kendo UI Editor when selecting a range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, richtextbox, kendo-editor

I'm using a Kendo UI Editor. I want to highlight the excess characters that are typed/pasted in the editor. This is what I've done:

```
$(function () {
    var $editor = $('#txt-editor');
    $editor.kendoEditor({
        keydown: ValidateRichTextEditor
    });
});

function ValidateRichTextEditor(e) {
    var editor = $(e.sender.textarea),
        kendoEditor = editor.data('kendoEditor'),
        characters = kendoEditor.body.innerText.length,
        limit = editor.data('valLengthMax');

    if (characters > limit) {
        var textNodes = getTextNodes(kendoEditor.body),
            charCount = 0,
            startNode, startOffset;

        for (var i = 0, textNode; textNode = textNodes[i++];) {
            var chars = charCount + textNode.length;
            if (limit < chars) {
                //set the text node as the starting node
                //if the characters hit the limit set
                startNode = textNode;
                startOffset = chars - charCount;
                break;
            }

            //add the length of the text node to the current character count
            charCount += textNode.length;
        }

        var range = kendoEditor.createRange();
        range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
        kendoEditor.selectRange(range);
        kendoEditor.document.execCommand('backColor', false, '#fcc');
    }
}

function getTextNodes(node) {
    var textNodes = [];
    //node type 3 is a text node
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    } else {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
            textNodes.push.apply(textNodes, getTextNodes(children[i]));
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dork/13173n7r/)

So far, the highlighting works but the cursor position is always at the position where the highlighting starts. How can I position the cursor so that it would remember the last place it was? Say for example I just keep on typing, the cursor should be at the end of the editor content. Or when I click somewhere in the middle of the content, the cursor should start where I clicked on the content.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/13173n7r/2/

Comment: @Joe thanks! but would you happen to know how to only highlight the characters that exceed the set limit? So when I go over the limit, set the cursor at the start, hit delete, the highlighted/unhighlighted characters should update

Comment: Does this help? It is a non-kendo discussion of the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749244/how-can-i-make-a-textarea-with-character-limit-highlighting-like-twitter

Answer (score 1):

If I am correctly interpreting your requirement, there is a much simpler solution than what you are attempting.

```
(function () {
    var $editor = $('#txt-editor'),
        limit = $editor.data('valLengthMax')
        limitExceeded = false;

    $editor.kendoEditor({
      keyup: ValidateRichTextEditor
    });

    function ValidateRichTextEditor(e) {
      var characters = this.body.innerText.length;

      console.log('\'' + this.body.innerText + '\' : ' + this.body.innerText.length);

      if (characters >= limit && !limitExceeded) {
        limitExceeded = true;
        this.exec('backColor', { value: '#fcc' });
      }
    }
})();
```

Update 1: This solution is a bit buggy. The backspace key causes some hiccups.

Update 2: After a lot of fiddling, you cannot trust `body.innerText.length`. It never returns the correct value once the background color style is executed. My reasoning is that the `<span>` elements that are added to the body are counted as characters and the backspace key does not remove them as would be expected.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/cicilokeqaxi/1/edit?js,console,output) is a JSBin example where you can read the console output as you type. Illogical to say the least.

Comment: Hi, @Brett. Thanks for your answer but it behaves much like Joe's fiddle (commented in my question). The characters that aren't supposed to be highlighted isn't updated when you exceed the limit and then place the cursor at the beginning of the editor.